# Need help in anchoring to different parts of the webpage based on my drop-down box input value

Tags: javascript, php, html

[Overview image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGyg3.jpg)

Hi everyone I'm doing a web database. And I would like to add new modules in my database. As shown in the image above, the format of my webpage is adding of new module tabs  and then a submission button followed by the data-table below. I want my webpage to anchor to the category(which i have selected in the drop-down menu) and also display the newly added module once i have "clicked" the submission button.

Once again, The moment I click the submit button 2 things should happen:
1. anchor to the category selected earlier in the drop down menu
2. the submitted module should be displayed at the anchored category

Here is my code in my html page:

```
<form align="center" method="post" id="urladdform" name="urladdform" action="add_mod_row.php?wikeeusername=<?=$_COOKIE['login_user']?>">
            <select required name="ddlcategory" id="ddlcategory" class="form-control" style="width:10%; margin-left:20%; float:left;">
                <option value="">Select Category</option>
                <option value="redFruits">Red Fruits</option>
                <option value="blueFruits">Blue Fruits</option>
                <option value="greenFruits">Green Fruits</option>
            </select>
            <input style="width:40%; float:left;" type="text" id="url2file" name="url2file" placeholder="Required" class="form-control"><br><br><input type="hidden" name="authkey" value="<?= $authkey?>"><br><button class="btn btn-info" id="addnewbutton" type="submit">Add to database</button>

        </form>
```

Here is the code in my javascript:

```
// Inserting of new module design into database. Creates a new row in admin table to input relevant information.
$("#addnewbutton").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var actForm=$(this).closest("form");
    var inputval=actForm.children('input').val();
    if(inputval.indexOf("https")>-1&&inputval.indexOf("HardLink")>-1)
    //if(inputval.indexOf("http")>-1&&inputval.indexOf("Virtual%20Documents")>-1)
    {
        window.location.href = '#ddlcategory'; 
        //$(".st-body-scroll").scrollTop(0); 
        var formData=actForm.serialize();
        var ddl = document.getElementById("ddlcategory");
        var selcat = ddl.value;
        var tableid = "#adminmodtable_"+selcat;
```

As seen in the javascript the Window location is anchored #ddlcategory. Which i thought would direct me to the input selected in the drop-down menu but now after clicking the SUBMIT button it just adds the new module but does not anchor to the category instead it highlights the category  input box, whose ID is ddlcategory.

I need help to anchor to the selected value of ddlcategory.
Sorry for the long post and thank you .